# Phonegap not loading external images?

Tags: html, cordova

I am trying to load remote images in my project urls are like this:

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg"/>
```

Now it is trying to load image from `file:///images/image.php`. It must load from `"BaseURL/images/image.jpg"`.

Could you also please tell how can set I base URL.

Answer (score 3):

what do you mean by external images. If the image is inside `www` directory,then it should be

```
<img src="images/image.jpg"/>
```

if it's in internal or external storage it'll look something like

```
<img src="file:///images/image.jpg"/>
```

if it's in web server, it will be

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg"/>
```